# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1584 Incorrect parameters in the call to stored function 'sphinx_snippets'

Tags: sql, laravel, sphinx

Search word using sphinx in my Laravel Script return this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1584 Incorrect parameters in the call to stored function 'sphinx_snippets' (SQL: select articles.*, sphinx_snippets(articles.title, 'articles', 'dff', 280 AS `limit`, 8 AS around, '<span class="highlight">' AS before_match, '</span>' AS after_match) as title_snippet, sphinx_snippets(articles.abstract, 'articles', 'dff', 280 AS `limit`, 8 AS around, '<span class="highlight">' AS before_match, '</span>' AS after_match) as abstract_snippet from `articles_index` inner join `articles` on `articles_index`.`id` = `articles`.`id` where articles_index.query = '@* dff;sort=relevance;fieldweights=title,2,abstract,1,keywords,10;mode=extended;offset=0;
limit=25')
```

What is the Solution.
also i run this code in mysql by terminal

```
select articles.*, sphinx_snippets(articles.title, 'articles', 'dff') as title_snippet from articles;
```

got error :

ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION database_name.sphinx_snippets does not exist

Comment: check the call to function how many parameters you are passing in it

Comment: That looks like a error message from MySQL. Do you have SphinxSE and the UDF installed? http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/sphinxse-snippets.html   http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/sphinxse-installing.html